# Could FCC-unapproved RF devices still be used legally?

Tags: fcc

If my reading is correct, FCC allows the use of RF devices that are unapproved. One condition is that it is used for the purpose of

> Evaluation of performance and determination of customer acceptability,
>   during developmental, design, or pre-production states.

ftp://ftp.fcc.gov/pub/Daily_Releases/Daily_Business/2013/db0321/DOC-319712A1.txt

I think the 'determination of customer acceptability' is a loose concept. What does it involve? Couldn't a customer be given a device for use for 3yrs and still be part of the 'customer acceptability' process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One indication would be that if the customer had not paid for it, it would still be under determination.

The FCC has big enforcement teeth, and fighting them could eat up [a lot of money](http://transition.fcc.gov/eb/marketing/) if they think you're playing fast and loose. Even if you win, the process will ensure you lose.